# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I am facing this issue in Angular 4 application in Internet Explorer, but in other browser it is running fine.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMdcO.png)

Comment: Until you share the code, no one will be able to help!

Comment: What Manu said! Plus, are you using the CLI? Have you gone through and uncommented all of the code required for your version of IE in the polyfills.ts file?

Comment: I have uncommented all imports in polyfill.ts.Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

With all information, probably you don't have a shim for [symbol replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/replace).

Comment: I have es6 shim as well core-js in package.json .still not working ,it is causing problem in Internet Explorer.Thank you anyway!

Comment: My guess was that its not implemented in IE and implemented in Chrome. :-) The best candidate is shim replace.